# Unique solution fo $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the equation $x^2+y^2+2z = cos(z)^2$. Show that if $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$ is any solution to the equation, then near $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$, the equation can be solved uniquely for $z$ (in terms of $x$ and $y$). Meanwhile, can we also always solve for $y$ (in terms of $x$ and $z$)?

My progress: I have calculated partial derivatives, but unable to determine how correlate it with given problems? Indeed, I am also struggling to understand the question itself. What they mean by "near $(x_{0},y_{0},z_{0})$"?  Any help will be strongly welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).
Let $F(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + 2 z - \cos(z)^2$.  The fact that
$\partial F/\partial z = 2 + 2 \sin(z) \cos(z) \ne 0$ for all real $z$ is what you need for one of the hypotheses of this theorem.  On the other hand, the fact that $\partial F/\partial y = 2 y$ can be $0$ means that you might not be able to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $z$.  Note that if $x^2 + 2 z - \cos(z)^2 > 0$ you certainly can't.